# what's the best way to display one color in full screen for a few seconds without switching activity?

Tags: android

I want to display just one color (any) in full-screen for a few seconds, but don't want to leave the current activity. almost like a white full screen flash. what will be the best way?

Comment: use Timer interval, & after certain time change the color

Answer (score 4):

You could have the activities layout where in you have a view which has  the height & width attribute as **match_parent** and has the

> android:visibility="gone"

attribute set, and then in your code you could have the view set to visible when you want to change the color using

> view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

and then using a timer or a thread you could revert back and hide that view again.
maybe something like this:

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a layout filling the whole screen with the color at your desire and controls its visibility from gone to visible and the other way around.
2. Use a foreground in your root layout. You don't need to add another view to your hierarchy but you need a drawable. Switch between:

`rootLayout.setForeground(R.drawable.color_drawable);`
`rootLayout.setForeground(null);`